# How to access values for a key in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Newbie Question:
I have a dictionary rendering with `extra_Context` from a method defined in views.py

My views:

```
 extra_context = {
    'comment': comment
    }
return direct_to_template(request, 'events/comment_detail.html', extra_context)
```

If i print the `comment` the it print like this:

```
[{'comment': u'first', 'user': 2}, {'comment': u'second', 'user': 2}]
```

I want to pass this dictionary to my template. I tried with this following code:

```
       <tbody>
            {% for obj in comment %}
                {% for key,val in obj.items %}
             <tr class="{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}">
                <td> {{val}}</td>
            </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
       </tbody>
```

It prints :

```
first
2
second
2
```

I want in this way:

```
first  2
second 2
```

..and so on

What should i add it to get like above ?

**Updated!**

```
 def comment_detail(request, object_id):
     comment_obj = EventComment.objects.filter(event = object_id)
     comment = comment_obj.values('comment','user')
     extra_context = {
         'comment': comment
         }
     return direct_to_template(request, 'events/comment_detail.html', extra_context)
```

comment_detail.html

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>{% trans "Comments" %}</th><th>{% trans "Timestamp "%}<th>{% trans "User" %}</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% if comments %}
    {% for com in comment %}
                <td> {{com.comment}}</enter code heretd>
                <td> {{com.user}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
     <td> No comments </td>
     {% endif %}
    </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that nested `for` iterating `k,v`. I just tried this:

View:

```
def testme(request):
   comments = []
   comments.append({'user': 2, 'comment': 'cool story bro'})
   comments.append({'user': 7, 'comment': 'yep. cool story'})

   extra_context = {
      'comments': comments
   }

   return render_to_response('testapp/testme.html', extra_context )
```

Template:

```
{% if comments %}
   <b>Comments:</b>
   <ul>
   {% for comment in comments %}
     <li>{{ comment.comment }} (id {{ comment.user }})</li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% else %}
   <b>No comments</b>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But the data which i have to append according to your reply i am getting from the database.Please take a look on updated! section of the question :)
I just posted the method in views.py

Comment: @AmitPal does it fails rendering the template? Could you add the error you get below the method you just added?

Comment: I have also add my template in update section. With using that it prints No comments in comment td

Comment: @AmitPal I think this is simply because the variable names doesn't match. You called it `comment` in your view, and in your template you call it `comments`.

Answer (score 1):

"for k(k=key), v(v=value) in object.items"

All that is saying is to iterate over every key value pair i.e. such as name = models.CharField(max_length=50) in object.items. Your view has returned context for object.items which each item is a model instance and has a set of k,v pairs associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question just about html markup.
Try this:

```
<tbody>
    {% for obj in comment %}
        <tr class="{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}">
            {% for key,val in obj.items %}          
                <td>{{val}}</td>       
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

or this:

```
<tbody>
    {% for obj in comment %}
        <tr class="{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}"><td>
            {% for key,val in obj.items %}          
                 {{val}}<span> </span>  
            {% endfor %}
        </td>  </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: have you seen that i did the same thing?
did you check the code written in template section

Comment: And your answer is wrong. It only prints the value of comment key not the value of user key. Please look at the question

Comment: Hm, you wrote `I want in this way: first  2 second 2`. So i thought, you want to print `first` and `2` on the same line in html output. For this i modified template code...

Comment: I think that it created a confusion to you :P,

Comment: Look @stalk answer again. It's not the same you've done. the `{% for key,val in obj.items %}` part is inside one row (`<tr>` tag)  which is what you want. In your case, you have one value per row, because the "for" template tag is outside the row tag. Have a look at it again...